# When does the Deadzone movie take place in the DBZ storyline?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball

During the story arc with Raditz they make it out as though it's the first time Piccolo and Goku team up.  With Goku dying in the Raditz fight and not showing up again until Vegeta, it couldn't have happened after that fight.  Where does it fit into the storyline before the Raditz fight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z%3a_Dead_Zone) explains it pretty well:

> Dead Zone is the only film that takes place after the end of Dragon Ball and before the beginning of Dragon Ball Z. The events of this movie can be placed into the series timeline between episodes "The End, The Beginning" of the Piccolo Jr. Saga and "The New Threat" of the Vegeta Saga.

Comment: So it's not actually part of either series?

Comment: @MCeley Exactly. Apparently, it's not in-the-series, but it's sort of link between the two. :)

Comment: This can't be true - Krillin recognizes Gohan as Goku's son in this movie.  He doesn't even find out that Goku has a son until the first episode of Dragon Ball Z.

Comment: @Zibbobz Re-read the quoted part. The events of the movie can be placed before the Vegeta Saga, so after Raditz comes to Earth.

Comment: @Alenanno That makes even less sense.  Gohan was kidnapped the day that he was introduced to Krillin, and Goku was killed in the rescue efforts, not coming back to life until Vegeta had already arrived on earth.

Comment: @Zibbobz True, the placement creates a few discrepancies with the other two series, [and they are known](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Dead_Zone), but then again, movies from anime series often show such discrepancies. Nothing new there.

Answer (score 1):

All of the Dragon ball Z films Were fillers.
Except these movies:

- Bardock: The Father of Goku
- The History of Trunks
- wrath of the dragon (Very questionable)

---

Edit: In most cases it does not really matter, because the information is not synchronized with the series itself.